# Bug in count in openFDA Adverse Events?

Tags: openfda

When using "count" I have found that less frequent counts in a query are often incorrect. My ad hoc workaround has been to always set limit to 999, and only use the first 100 counts.  For example,

the following query

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:([20000101+TO+20170101])&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&skip=0

indicates there are 13428 reports with patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact=NEUTROPENIA.

This query

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact:(NEUTROPENIA)+AND+receivedate:([20000101+TO+20170101])&limit=1

indicates there are 26220 such reports.

Interestingly, this (with ... replaced by text in previous links):

.../drug/event.json?search=receivedate:([20000101+TO+20170101])&limit=999&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&skip=0

also indicates there are 26220 reports.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: in case it's of any value as an alternative..  you could just download the entire data set.  http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/fda%20adverse%20event%20reporting%20system%20%28faers%29